# Is this undefined behavior in C?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, side-effects, logical-or, logical-and

The expression `b = 5 << sizeof(a++);` is an undefined behavior. But is `c = a && b << --a;` or  `c = a || b << a++;` also an undefined behavior? I think it is undefined behavior, but I am not sure.

Comment: Why do you think it's UB? Why might it not be?

Comment: For that matter, why is `b = 5 << sizeof(a++);` UB?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: In our lecture we said that this is a UB, or not?

Comment: Did the lecture explain why?

Comment: I don't think any of these are undefined. Logical operators are sequence points as far as I know.

Comment: `b = 5 << sizeof(a++);` is UB only when `5 << sizeof(a++)` overflows, ie, when `a` is of a "large" type .. but there are no types in C, where `++` makes sense that can be that large :)

Comment: @pmg: `b = 5 << sizeof(a++)` also has undefined behavior when `a` does not have a real or pointer type or is not a modifiable lvalue, when `b` is not a modifiable lvalue or is not an arithmetic type.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: He said "we should not have any side effects within the operands of an sizeof operator"

Comment: @s96: If your teacher said “we should not have any side effects within the operands of an sizeof operator” because such side effects might give rise to undefined behavior, they are wrong. The operand of `sizeof` is not evaluated unless it is a variable length array type, so no side effects occur for `sizeof(a++)`. There is no rule that mere presence of side effects in a `sizeof` operand causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Does that mean if we have && or || (sequence points) that we automatically don't have undefined behavior? If not do you have an example?

Comment: @s96 When compiled, `sizeof(a++)` should result in a warning: *"warning: expression with side effects has no effect in an unevaluated context"* That doesn't mean it's undefined behavior, but it does mean that your teacher is correct that you *"should not have any side effects within the operands of a sizeof operator"*.

Comment: @TomKarzes: The behavior of `1/0` is undefined, and undefined means the C standard does not require an error to occur, since it means the C standard does not require anything. Clang gives a warning by default if it sees this as constants, but it does not produce an error.

Comment: I tend to not even attempt to understand such code. I just reject it in a code review.

Comment: `sizeof(a++)` has exactly the same effect as `sizeof(a)`, so it is not undefined, but **useless**. Don't write useless code!

Answer (score 7):

> He said "we should not have any side effects within the operands of an sizeof operator" [From a comment, apparently the reason `b = 5 << sizeof(a++);` was said to have undefined behavior.]

If the teacher said this because such side effects might give rise to undefined behavior, they are wrong. The operand of `sizeof` is not evaluated unless it is a variable length array type (C 2018 6.5.3.4 2), so no side effects occur for `sizeof(a++)`. Further, even if the expression were evaluated, there is no rule that mere presence of side effects in a `sizeof` operand causes undefined behavior.

None of the displayed statements have undefined behavior *per se*. (Some definitions and values for `a`, `b`, and `c` might give rise to undefined behavior.)

In `c = a && b << --a;`, the left operand of `&&`, `a`, is specified to be evaluated before the right operand, `b << --a`, and there is a sequence point between them (C 2018 6.5.13 4), so the fact that `--a` modifies `a` and `a` is also used in the left operand does not trigger the rule (C 2018 6.5 2) that behavior is undefined if a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to a use of its value.

Similarly, in `c = a || b << a++;`, there is a sequence point between evaluation of the left operand `a` and the right operand `b << a++` (C 2018 6.5.14 4).

Answer (score 5):

This statement

```
b = 5 << sizeof(a++);
```

is a valid expression statement. There is no undefined behavior. Pay attention to that the expression used in the operator `sizeof` is not evaluated.

The undefined behavior can occur in this statement in one case (the C Standard. 6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators)

> If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or
> equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is
> undefined.

But the type `size_t` of an expression with the `sizeof`  operator is an unsigned integer type a value of which can not be negative.

In the other two statements

```
c = a && b << --a;
```

and

```
c = a || b << a++;
```

that are equivalent to

```
c = ( a ) && ( b << --a );
```

and

```
c = ( a ) || ( b << a++ );
```

neither one has undefined behavior because there is a sequence point after the evaluation of the first operand of the logical operators AND and OR.

From the C Standard (6.5.13 Logical AND operator)

> 4 Unlike the bitwise binary & operator, the && operator guarantees
> left-to-right evaluation; if the second operand is evaluated, **there
> is a sequence point between the evaluations of the first and second
> operands**. If the first operand compares equal to 0, the second
> operand is not evaluated.

and (6.5.14 Logical OR operator)

> 4 Unlike the bitwise | operator, the || operator guarantees
> left-to-right evaluation; if the second operand is evaluated, **there
> is a sequence point between the evaluations of the first and second
> operands.** If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second
> operand is not evaluated.

The undefined behavior can occur only in the sub-expressions with the shift operator provided that these operands will be evaluated when values of the expressions `--a` or `a++` are negative or too big. See the quote from the C Standard in the beginning of the answer.

Here is a correct demonstration program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 10;

    int c = a && b << --a;

    printf ( "a = %d, b = %d, c = %d\n", a, b, c );

    c = a || b << a++;

    printf ( "a = %d, b = %d, c = %d\n", a, b, c );
}
```

The program output is

```
a = 0, b = 10, c = 1
a = 1, b = 10, c = 1
```

In the both expressions

```
b << --a
```

and

```
b << a++
```

the value of the right operand of the shift-left operator is equal to `0`. So the value of the expressions is equal to `10` because no shifting was done.